# XmlReader.ReadToFollowing Method

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to read some sections from xml file, but it only reads first, why?

here is the code:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("settings.xml"))
{
     if(reader.ReadToFollowing("LastProcessingId"))
         Console.Write(reader.ReadElementContentAsInt());
     if(reader.ReadToFollowing("TotalNumberFolders"))
         Console.Write(reader.ReadElementContentAsInt());
     if(reader.ReadToFollowing("LastAccessTime"))
         Console.Write(reader.ReadElementContentAsDateTime());
}
```

seems that second call of  reader.ReadToFollowing don't work after call of this line 
`Console.Write(reader.ReadElementContentAsInt());`

xml file is :

```
<Settings>
  <LastProcessingId>3</LastProcessingId>
  <TotalNumberFolders>20</TotalNumberFolders>
  <LastAccessTime>2014-05-06T00:00:00+04:00</LastAccessTime>
</Settings>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML file contents as well?

Comment: It seems you may be need a loop to read over the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code worked for me

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("settings.xml"))
{
    reader.MoveToContent();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: ",reader.Name);
            // Next read will contain text.
            if (reader.Read()) Console.WriteLine("{0}: ", reader.Value);
        }                    
    }                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A year has passed, but no one ever really answered the OP's problem. ReadToFollowing should be used to find the first node and then use ReadToNextSibling should be used as [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf7w4zx9(v=vs.110).aspx). Example:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("books.xml")) {
    reader.ReadToFollowing("book");
    do {
       Console.WriteLine("ISBN: {0}", reader.GetAttribute("ISBN")); 
    } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("book"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually see examples with `Read` and switch statement.  I have created a working example with `ReadToFollowing`:

The `books.xml` file:

```
<bookstore>
    <book genre='Science Fiction'>
        <title>Dune</title>
        <author>Frank Herbert</author>
        <price>8.99</price>
    </book>
    <book genre='Novel'>
        <title>Old Goriot</title>
        <author>Honoré de Balzac</author>
        <price>9.0</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

C# code example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace Simple
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var reader = XmlReader.Create("books.xml");

            reader.ReadToFollowing("book");

            do
            {
                reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
                Console.WriteLine($"genre: {reader.Value}");

                reader.ReadToFollowing("title");
                Console.WriteLine($"title: {reader.ReadElementContentAsString()}");

                reader.ReadToFollowing("author");
                Console.WriteLine($"author: {reader.ReadElementContentAsString()}");

                reader.ReadToFollowing("price");
                Console.WriteLine($"price: {reader.ReadElementContentAsString()}");

                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");

            } while (reader.ReadToFollowing("book"));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ dotnet run
genre: Science Fiction
title: Dune
author: Frank Herbert
price: 8.99
-------------------------
genre: Novel
title: Old Goriot
author: Honoré de Balzac
price: 9.0
-------------------------
```

Answer (score -3):

Read all nodes use:

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {

            }
```

But I use Linq for read XML:

```
<customers>
  <customer id="84">
    <name value="Sample Name" />
  </customer>

  <customer id="89">
    <name value="Sample Name 2" />
  </customer>

  <customer id="80">
    <name value="Sample Name 3" />
  </customer>
</customers>
```

using this code:

```
XmlNode searched = null;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\Temporary\customers.xml");

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/customers/customer"))
{


}
```

OR

```
XElement main = XElement.Load(@"D:\Temporary\customers.xml");

            IEnumerable<XElement> searched =
                from c in main.Elements("customer")
                select c;
```

Comment: This is not a XmlReader solution